# set TreeItem to TreeTableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, treetable

I try to set children for root. But somehow my root is empty, although treeNodes is loaded and has value in it.

```
TreeItem<String> treeNodes = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {

         treeNodes
        = new TreeItem<>(rows.get(i));
        //rows.get(i)
         System.out.println(treeNodes);//is initialized

         root.getChildren().setAll(treeNodes);
         System.out.println(root);//is emty
    }
final TreeTableView<String> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(
            root);
TreeTableColumn<String, TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> firstColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>();
    treeTableView.getColumns().add(firstColumn);// Tree column but no item in it, just an arrow facing down.
```

Comment: You need a [cell value factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty) for your column; your types look wrong though, I don't know how your cell value factory will generate a `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` from a `String`.

Comment: i will do it. in fact i thought it is possible to save treemap key=value in treeitem and set the value as name of each node and then walk the keys for other calculations.

Comment: i guess ReadOnlyMapProperty is what i need. but i am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> functions = new ArrayList<String>(dc.getNameOfFunction());
TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Functions");
for (Entry<String, String> entryRow : dc.getSortedfuncAll().entrySet()) {
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(entryRow.getValue()));

    }
final TreeTableView<String> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(root);
```